# Output multiple instances of class from single Entity Framework row

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-6.0

We currently have the following code:

```
return await Table.AsNoTracking().Select(d => new MyClass()
{
    Code = d.Code1,
    Name = d.Desc1,
    Type = "Test",
    Template = $"test-{item}"
}).Where(d =>
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Code) &&
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Name)
).Distinct().ToArrayAsync();
```

We also have another query that does this:

```
return await Table.AsNoTracking().Select(d => new MyClass()
{
    Code = d.Code2,
    Name = d.Desc2,
    Type = "Test",
    Template = $"test-{item}"
}).Where(d =>
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Code) &&
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Name)
).Distinct().ToArrayAsync();
```

Essential a single record can output multiple instances of a class.
In order to improve effiency, it would be good to do this as a single query and have all instances of a class generated.

I tried something like the following but Entity Framework doesn't know how to convert it. Any ideas what could be done?

```
return await Table.AsNoTracking().Select(d => new List<MyClass>()
{
    new MyClass()
    {
        Code = d.Code2,
        Name = d.Desc2,
        Type = "Test",
        Template = $"test-{item}"
    },
    new MyClass()
    {
        Code = d.Code1,
        Name = d.Desc1,
        Type = "test",
        Template = $"test-{item}"
    } 
}).SelectMany(d => d, (d, i) => i).Where(d =>
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Code) &&
    !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Name)
).Distinct().ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: A tuple could work `list.Select(d => (firstclass, secondclass))....`

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This wouldn't provide a single list and instead an array of tuple?

Comment: Your `Where` conditions are the same in both cases. Should you be checking `d.Code1` in the first case and `d.Code2` in the second case?

Comment: @JackA. - no, because it is already projected to myclass which only has the member Code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `Union`, it should even remove needs to call `Distict`

```cs
var query1 = Table
    .Select(d => new MyClass()
    {
        Code = d.Code1,
        Name = d.Desc1,
        Type = "Test",
        Template = $"test-{item}"
    }).Where(d =>
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Code) &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Name)
    );

var query2 = Table
    .Select(d => new MyClass()
    {
        Code = d.Code2,
        Name = d.Desc2,
        Type = "Test",
        Template = $"test-{item}"
    }).Where(d =>
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Code) &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(d.Name)
    );

var result = await query1.Union(query2)
    .ToArrayAsync();
```

Comment: That's perfect and fixes a potential bug we found too! Thanks